# Trying to query the Lead's Owner's UserRecordAccess .HasReadAccess

Tags: apex, trigger, query

I want to query a Lead record and find out if the Lead's Owner has read access.  I tried the following query but it fails.

```
select Id, Owner.UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess from lead WHERE Id = '<myid>'
```

The error returned is:

> Didn't understand relationship 'UserRecordAccess' in field path.

Comment: If you look in the SFDC Object doc for [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm?search_text=order), you'll see there is no relationship field to `UserRecordAccess`

Comment: Doesn't the lead owner always have read access?  If you meant current user then you can do subquery but beware that the results are returned on an object level and not a record level as you would expect. So the user may not have read access to the record but does on the object and it would return true for read access when doing it as a subquery. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4NxAAK

Answer (score 2):

You can't use subquery to check `UserRecordAccess` fields value

So pass the recordId and ownerId/userId.. to check that user having what type of access on that record.. and RecordId will be lead Id/sobject id

you can check variables like `HasReadAccess`.

```
List<UserRecordAccess> lstUserRecordAccess = [SELECT RecordId,MaxAccessLevel,HasAllAccess, 
                                                     HasDeleteAccess, 
                                                     HasEditAccess,
                                                     HasReadAccess, 
                                                     HasTransferAccess 
                                                FROM UserRecordAccess 
                                               WHERE UserId = 'Pass user Id' 
                                                 AND RecordId = 'Pass lead Id'];
```

Comment: So I would have to do a separate query to find out the HasReadAccess value?  I can't include it in the original query?

Comment: @user31673 do a a separate query for HasReadAccess value. Salesforce doesn't allow subquery

Comment: Side note... The owner always has read access.